# How do I graph and calculate the number of people that have access to my product?

Tags: google-maps, maps

I have a product in a shopping centres around the country. I want to graph these locations and also work how how many people in a 20km vicinity have access to my device.

I have access to population data per post code but a 20km radius wouldn't cover a complete suburb so I would need to calculate the 20% of each suburb that the radius covers.

How do I even begin?

Comment: Could you elaborate your question. How your devices communicate. What kind of mapping are you looking for and how frequent is your data updated ?

Comment: Also, which platform are developing on?

Comment: was just planning to make a custom google map